# I am using room database and one of my function should return a Flow<List<History>>. But I get an error when I Add Flow<>

Tags: kotlin, dynamic, android-room, kotlin-flow

I am a beginner and I built a calculator app to learn android development and decided to add a history. However, the history view isn't updated dynamically, for example: when I delete a history I can still see it, when I go back and then re-enter to the history view it's gone. I want the update to be done immediately.

Here is the [link of the project](https://github.com/Michella-AbiNader/Calc_App.git).

Here is my entity:

```
package com.example.calcapp

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
data class History(
    val equation: String,
    val answer: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)
```

Here is the dao:

```
package com.example.calcapp

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface HistoryDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(history: History)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(history: History)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun display(): List<History>

    @Query("DELETE FROM history")
    suspend fun clearHistory()

}
```

here is the state:

```
package com.example.calcapp

data class HistoryState(
    val history: List<History> = emptyList(),
    val equation: String = "",
    val answer: String = "",
    val isHistory: Boolean = false,
)
```

Here is the event:

```
package com.example.calcapp

sealed interface HistoryEvent{
    object SaveHistory: HistoryEvent
    data class SetEquation(val equation: String):  HistoryEvent
    data class SetAnswer(val answer: String):  HistoryEvent
    object ShowHistory: HistoryEvent
    object HideHistory: HistoryEvent
    data class DeleteHistory(val history: History): HistoryEvent
    object ClearHistory: HistoryEvent

}
```

Here is the viewModel:

```
package com.example.calcapp

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class HistoryViewModel(
    private val dao: HistoryDao
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(HistoryState())
    val state = _state

    fun onEvent(event: HistoryEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is HistoryEvent.DeleteHistory -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.delete(event.history)
                }
            }

            HistoryEvent.HideHistory -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        isHistory = false
                    )
                }
            }

            HistoryEvent.SaveHistory -> {
                val equation = state.value.equation
                val answer = state.value.answer

                val history = History(equation, answer)
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.insert(history)
                }

                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        equation = "",
                        answer = ""
                    )
                }
            }

            is HistoryEvent.SetAnswer -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        answer = event.answer
                    )
                }
            }

            is HistoryEvent.SetEquation -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        equation = event.equation
                    )
                }
            }

            HistoryEvent.ShowHistory -> {
                var history = emptyList<History>()
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    history = dao.display()
                }
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        history = history,
                        isHistory = true
                    )
                }
            }

            HistoryEvent.ClearHistory -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.clearHistory()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried:

`@Query("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id ASC") fun display(): Flow<List<History>>`

But I got an error in my viewModel, made changes there still got an error in the HistoryState. What should I do?